# Definition of "concept" and "conceptual field in cognitive linguistics

Tags: semantics, lexical-semantics, cognitive-linguistics

I am writing a Master's thesis dedicated to the conception field "business" in Modern English Language.  The definition of "concept" and "conceptional field" is greatly discussed by Russian linguists, there are a lot of works dedicated to this theme. Could you please advise me the latest works on this subject in the English language? Probably some of you can name the researchers who explore this subject? Your help will be highly appreciated.